# How to obtain a generic search/find method with spring data?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

All I need is to provide all my repositories with a generic search/find method.
Something like this:

```
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> {

    Iterable<T> search(SearchParameters sp);

}
```

where the `SearchParameters` object represents a set of values for each property, and probably a condition to apply on them.

Jpa Criteria is probably the way to go, but I'm really having a hard time finding something that fits my needs.

Comment: Have you tried using `Specifications`? [2.3 in spring data jpa reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#specifications)

Comment: Yes. However it is not easy to "stay generic", even using specifications. At least I don't know how. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used one approach which goes in the same direction but i would rather say its a dynamic approach instead of generic. Its now working pretty well and we are able to generate all desired filters automatically by just giving the search entity. I also thought the criteria api is the way to go but after a while it just got too messy with all the side effects and i turned around creating the query string with parameters myself.

I created an entityscanner which takes all domain entities and generates filterdefinition objects for each desired filter. This scanner takes an entity and follows properties up to a certain level (to keep the amount of filters at bay). I cannot give you the code here since that belongs to a customer but the approach i can provide.

What i needed in the filterdefinition is this: entitytype, propertypath, propertytype, valuesexpression in case we render options (think masterdata), joins needed (to avoid joining several times the same tables), open/closed bracket. This is the definition of a filter.

Then you need a value object holding the current configuration of a user: Inputvalue, operator (>=), brackets, filter link (and/or) .

With this we can render a completly dynamic filter engine with some small limitations. I.e i did not implement parent searches of the same entity yet.

You might start simple an generate a sub query for each filter. Like: where id in (select ....) and/or id in (select ...)  This works ok if the amount of entities is not too high but you will feel the performance penalty of several subqueries if the amount of rows in the domain entity table is high. 
Then you dive in and find a way to separate the joins needed for a property path and in the querycreator you fiddle out the way of joining entities only again if neccessary.

As said. Start simple. Take first level properties of simple types like string and create your query engine. Enhance it by following specific entity joins and after you can go crazy and introduce expressions fetching options for a select rendering or use the conversion service for input parameters and so on.